# Can I prevent StackOverflowException from crashing my debuggee in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-debugging, stack-overflow, watch-window

I'm debugging a 3rd party library that is littered with properties that occasionally throw StackOverFlowException.

Whenever I look at objects from this library in the Watch window, I end up getting the error message "Function evaluation was aborted" and the app I'm debugging crashes.

I wrote an example of a property that reproduces this (when trying to evaluate it in the Watch window):

```
    private static int CausesStackoverflow
    {
        get { return CausesStackoverflow; }
    }
```

Is there any way to evaluate properties in the Watch window without risking my app crashing due to a Stackoverflow?

Comment: Do you mean that you need the Watch window to tell you that your example code is infinitely recursive?

Comment: Just to be clear: Your simple property sample is not simple, it is broken. Furthermore: A StackOverflow cause the application to be terminated. What exactly are you expecting? There is no proper way of recovering from StackOverflow. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, I want the Watch window to tell me that a StackoverflowException was caused by the function evaluated, but without crashing the entire application. The code fragment I included is just as an example, I realize it is broken, but I can't change the 3rd party code I am trying to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You should **prevent** (using counters or other tricks) and not **catch** StackOverflowExceptions.

Since this is 3rd party code (so I suppose it can't be changed) you can try this:

---

Starting with 2.0 a StackOverflow Exception **can only be caught in the following circumstances**.

> 1. The CLR is being run in a hosted environment where the host specifically allows for StackOverflow exceptions to be handled
> 2. The stackoverflow exception is thrown by user code and not due to an actual stack overflow situation (Reference)

---

From [MSDN StackOverflowException page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception.aspx):

> In prior versions of the .NET
>   Framework, your application could
>   catch a StackOverflowException object
>   (for example, to recover from
>   unbounded recursion). However, that
>   practice is currently discouraged
>   because significant additional code is
>   required to reliably catch a stack
>   overflow exception and continue
>   program execution.
>
> Starting with the .NET Framework
>   version 2.0, a StackOverflowException
>   object cannot be caught by a try-catch
>   block and the corresponding process is
>   terminated by default. Consequently,
>   users are advised to write their code
>   to detect and prevent a stack
>   overflow. For example, if your
>   application depends on recursion, use
>   a counter or a state condition to
>   terminate the recursive loop. Note
>   that an application that hosts the
>   common language runtime (CLR) can
>   specify that the CLR unload the
>   application domain where the stack
>   overflow exception occurs and let the
>   corresponding process continue. For
>   more information, see
>   ICLRPolicyManager Interface and
>   Hosting the Common Language Runtime.